# Redirecting from /index.php to / not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The dynamic pages in my site are configured with following htaccess rule:

```
# Dynamic Pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So the page is redirected from

```
http://example.com/?url=testpage
```

to

```
http://example.com/testpage/
```

But I also want to redirect /index.php to / (root). So when someone enters

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

in the browser address bar then it should go to

```
http://example.com/
```

To achieve this, I tried following rule:

```
#index.php to /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301]
```

Though this is working fine but it is affecting my previous htaccess rule. And the following URL

```
http://example.com/testpage/
```

automatically becomes

```
http://example.com/?url=testpage
```

When I remove this rule then previous dynamic page rule works fine. How can I keep both rules working in my htaccess file without conflicting each other?

My complete .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

#Enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Dynamic Pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# index.php to /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

#Enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# Dynamic Pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Important is to use `THE_REQUEST` in first rule so that you don't get rewrite loop. Clear your browser cache to test.

Comment: Wow! that worked like a charm even though I couldn't understand the rules.

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`